# how to Filter JSON data fetched from UrlFetchApp

Tags: javascript, json, google-apps-script, filter, urlfetch

I have the following code ..

```
function getAllNotes() {
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
var sheet = ss.getSheetByName('ALL_Notes'); 
sheet.getRange('A3:A').clear();
const url1 = "https://sample.com";
const response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url1, {"method": "GET",
"headers": {
"APIKEY": "???????????????????????????????",
"cache-control": "no-cache",
"Content-Type": "application/json"},
"muteHttpExceptions": true,
"followRedirects": true,
"validateHttpsCertificates": true,
"contentType": "application/json"});
var json = response.getContentText();
var dataAll = JSON.parse(json);
var finalData = dataAll["data"];
Logger.log(finalData);
```

the output from this code is as follows ..

> Logging output too large. Truncating output. [{Note={created=2021-07-25 09:34:24, NoteAttachment=[], user_permissions=null, follow_up_id=null, type=0, action_id=null, id=11, partner_type=1, share_with_partner=0, partner_id=75, **modified**=2021-07-26 08:30:50, item_id=75, status_id=null, body=
>
> td {border: 1px solid #ccc;}br {mso-data-placement:same-cell;}<span style="font-size:10pt;font-family:Tahoma,Arial;font-weight:normal{&formula="=iferror(index(,0))," ")">
>
> , show_preview=null, date=2021-07-25 09:33:00, item_type=1, staff_id=3, client_permissions=null, branch_id=1, url=null}}, {Note={**modified**=2021-07-26 08:29:43, created=2021-07-26 08:29:43, staff_id=3, date=2021-07-26 08:29:00, item_type=1, NoteAttachment=[], id=12, partner_id=106, share_with_partner=0, type=0, url=null, item_id=106, user_permissions=null, action_id=null, follow_up_id=null, partner_type=1, status_id=3, show_preview=null, client_permissions=null, branch_id=1, body=
>
> <span data-sheets-value{"1&qu[null,2,16711680],"15":"Tahoma","16":10}" data-sheets-formula="=iferror(indexstatus_id=3, follow_up_id=null, date=2021-07-26 09:58:00, action_id=null, staff_id=3, user_permissions=null, id=14, modified=2021-07-26 09:58:58, item_type=1, type=0, NoteAttachment=[], partner_id=113, url=null}}, {Note={share_with_partner=0, follow_up_id=null, staff_id=3, **modified**=2021-07-26 10:28:23, status_id=3, body=
>
> <span data-sheets-value="{"

It is too much. How to filter the output according to the value of `modified` so that my code only fetch data based on a specified value?

Comment: youget an array of notes, and now you have to loop oder this array to extract the data. for example `for(let i=0;i<finalData.length;i++) console.log(finalData[i].modified); `. Most users here are here because they want to learn and share knowledge, not to "just solve problems" so i doubt anyone will post a copy&paste ready solution. also it is not known what format the real finaldata should be

Comment: i tried your solution and it returned values of (modified) only. i want it to return all the data same as before but filtered according to (modified) value. p.s. i edited the last row of my question. thank you

Comment: if you want to filter you could use `console.log(finalData.filter(v => v.modified>'2021-11-01 00:00:00'))` as an example

Comment: thank you @mech for the quick responses very appreciated. the json output structure is as follows: **data [{Note={modified=2021-07-25 09:34:24,..etc**, so `console.log(finalData.filter(v => v.modified>'2021-11-01 00:00:00'))` received null. Should i put **Note** before it? because i search in the web and as I understand it should be _data_ >> _Note_ >> _modified_

Comment: Try `v.Note.modified` instead of `v.modified`. Practice [filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter)  and arrays

Comment: yeah of course, i forgot Note ;)